How to do Spring Auto Configuration for my external / third party module?
I am developing a module that is supposed to be used by other people in their projects.
Lets say, I am developing a YMLDataConnector that connects to a YML DB. If the user does not explicitly create an instance of 'YMLDataConnector', i want to create a default instance of 'YMLDataConnector' using AutoConfiguration so the user project can use it.
I have decent idea of AutoConfiguration. From what I understand, spring looks for spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties and spring.factories files in spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar to detect Beans that should be autoconfigured.
After defining/creating the AutoConfiguration Classes for my default YMLDataConnector bean, how can i inform spring to AutoConfigure this bean in the same way spring does it for other beans like  DataSource or HikariDataSource etc.  I ask this as spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar/META-INF/autoconfigure-metadata.properties will not have any idea about my YMLDataConnector default bean.
Will it work if i create META-INF/autoconfigure-metadata.properties and META-INF/spring.factories in the yml-data-connector.jar and do similar setup as in spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar.  Else please suggest the correct approach.
One additional question - what is difference between spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties vsspring.factories. I see spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties has the required setup, then what is the purpose of spring.factories
